# Can Fork-Exec mechanism support process authentication in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fork, exec, digital-signature

Assume that the linux kernel integrity is well guaranteed by a specific mechanism (secure boot for example).
I want to implement a native integrity check mechanism on Linux that authenticate every process to guarantee that only signed process can be executed.

The idea is:

1. at generation of rootfs, we generate an RSA key pair and sign every compiled binary program with the private key and attach signature to the file in an ELF metadata user section.
2. delete private key from memory at the end of generation
3. add in kernel Fork-Exec mechanism (or maybe only exec) the public key and a code to check signature of every transmitted program file to exec.

Is this possible and does this approach guarantee that only signed program will be executed?

Comment: execve already checks permissions, etc., so that would be the place to add an additional check.   https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/fs/exec.c#L1503

Comment: @stark yes sure since execve will be responsible of loading binary content but do you think the approach can guarantee authenticity of programs?